# How to Autowire a dynamic class

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to Autowire fields on a dynamic class?

Using a factory is great, but it doesn't allow me to `@Autowire` fields.

```
public static Workflow factory(WorkflowEntity workflowEntity) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(workflowEntity.getClassName())
                .asSubclass(Workflow.class);
        Object workflowClass = clazz.getConstructor(WorkflowEntity.class).newInstance(workflowEntity);
        return (Workflow) workflowClass;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.severe("Unable to instantiate "+workflowEntity.getClassName()+" class: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to do this, but in a way where Spring will process autowired fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring to autowire fields, it needs to be in charge of creating the object. Since you are creating the object in some Factory class, Spring cannot inject fields. For example, if you did

```
Object o = new ObjectWithAutowiredFields();
```

How would Spring know to autowire that object's fields, it hasn't even scanned the class.

However, if your factory is a Spring bean, you can have `@Autowired` fields in it and use those with the constructor of the class you're instantiating (given that class has such a constructor) or with setters.

Comment: I'm familiar with why `@Autowire` doesn't work in the current circumstances.  I'm just not sure if there's a way within Spring to load a class from the class name, like `com.project.package.class`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring

Comment: Interesting... even with `@Configurable`, it wouldn't change the fact that I'm loading the class manually.  What do I do about that?

Comment: I don't know if you can do anything but set the fields yourself.