# React to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException inside Spring Application Context

Tags: java, spring

We have an application context inside a web application. Whenever a typed-bean is requested which is not available in the context we have to create it and add it to the context.

The context will basically have to react to a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` by using a factory to create it.

For those wondering why we don't create them beforehand or use a FactoryBeans: Due to the highly dynamic nature of how the legacy middleware and the other layers interact we don't have a chance to know the service-types beforehand.

Any suggestions?

As mentioned in the comment below: [Registering beans(prototype) at runtime in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring)

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring