# How to load Groovy object from text file by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, groovy

**I have:**

Some interface:

```
public interface ISomeObject {
    void someAction();
}
```

Some groovy file (someObject.groovy):

```
public class SomeObject implements ISomeObject {
    @Autowired
    SomeOtherClass someField;
    @Override
    void someAction(){};
}
```

**I need to Spring automatically load autowired fields. How should I load this class?**

Some code (for start) that load class without Spring:

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class clazz = null;
try {
    clazz = gcl.parseClass(new File("someObject.groovy"));
    ISomeObject groovyObject = (ISomeObject ) clazz.newInstance();
    return Optional.of(groovyObject);
} catch (IOException |InstantiationException|IllegalAccessException e) {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem really is. Do you want to autowire dynamically loaded classes or what?

Comment: Yes, I want load groovy classes from text files and I need autowired fields in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use a plain old factory in this case and wire all the properties "manually".

Although I made a small research and it looks like you have other options to do it. I believe this question is what you are looking for:
[Registering beans(prototype) at runtime in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring)