# What ApplicationContext should I extend to use a folder as location and to refresh it on folder change?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to create an [ApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) that uses all the files from a given folder as bean configurations. The context should refresh, add and remove the beans based on directory file changes. I can use the [Apache Commons Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) to monitor the folder changes. I would like to have a hierarchical application context that has several children that can be refreshed, destroyed or initialized on changes of directory files.

Comment: Maybe this could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring