# Manual bean registration and configuration order

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I had an issue with spring's `@Order` annotation, it seems i can't get it to work in my application. Hence I managed to create a test class that imitates the very same behaviour which `@Order` does not have any effect on my components. The following test fails to run because of lack of bean typed `javax.sql.Datasource`:

```
package com.so;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestSpring {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Class<?>[] classes = new Class[]{AConf.class, ADAO.class, AService.class, RepoConf.class} ;
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(classes);
   }

   @Configuration
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 100)
   public static class AConf {

      @Autowired
      AService aService;

   }

   @Repository
   @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public static class ADAO {

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("myds")
      DataSource dataSource;
   }

   @Service
   @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public static class AService {

      @Autowired
      ADAO adao;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
         System.out.println("service init");
      }
   }

//   @Component does not have any effect
   @Configuration
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public static class RepoConf {

      @Autowired
      BeanFactory beanFactory;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
         ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
         configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("myds", new AbstractDataSource() {
            @Override
            public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
               return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
               return null;
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

Manual bean registration has risks as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751503/1941560, although I cannot find out in which circumtances that `@Order` annotation works. For above configuration of application I expect the execution order like; `RepoConf`, `AConf`, `ADAO`, `AService`.

A weird thing to notice is that when I changed the order of component classes declared to (with commencing array with `RepoConf`):

```
Class<?>[] classes = new Class[]{RepoConf.class, AConf.class, ADAO.class, AService.class};
```

or changed my `AConf` class to:

```
   @Configuration
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 100)
   public static class AConf {

      @Autowired
      RepoConf repoConf; // must be declared before aService

      @Autowired
      AService aService;

   }
```

application works as expected. Could someone explain that spring container's behaviour and how can I utilize `@Order` annotations?

**springframework version I use is 4.2.1.RELEASE**

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the [JavaDoc documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) for the `@Order` annotation, I don't think it is used to order bean creation:

> NOTE: Annotation-based ordering is supported for specific kinds of 
>   components only — for example, for annotation-based AspectJ aspects. 
>   Ordering strategies within the Spring container,  on the other hand, are 
>   typically based on the Ordered interface in order to allow for 
>   programmatically configurable ordering of each instance.

Consulting the Spring Framework [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), the `@Ordered` annotation seems to be used for:

- Ordering of instances when [injected into a collection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation)
- Ordering the execution of [event listeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-events-annotation)
- Ordering of `@Configuration` class processing, for example if you want to override a bean by name.

From the documentation, it does not look like `@Order` is intended for your use case.

However, from the Spring documentation, we can see there [`depends-on`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-dependson), which enforces that certain beans should be created before the bean being defined. This has a corresponding annotation [`@DependsOn`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html).

Comment: I tried `@Order` only on `RestConf` and `AConf` configurations, it should already be alright with this usage but i did not work either. What does overriding bean by name mean?

Comment: If you have two beans with the same name, one bean overrides the other, for example if you have the beans with the same name in multiple context XML files, which you can control with the order of the files. Spring beans can also be defined in `@Configuration` classes, and `@Order` puts an order to the `@Configuration` classes, so if you have multiple `@Configuration` classes defining a `@Bean` with the same name, the `@Configuration` class with the highest priority gets to create the `@Bean` with that name. `@Order` definitely seems like the wrong usage. `@DependsOn` seems like a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your version of Spring Framework simply ignores the `@Order` annotation on configuration classes. There's no surprise here, because that annotation should only be used on classes that implement the `Ordered` interface. Moreover, I could never find any reference to it about configuration classes in Spring Framework reference documentation.

Anyway you are walking in *terra incognita* here. It is not described in official documentation, so it will work or not depending on implementation details.  What happens here is (seeing the results):

- the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` first instantiate the configuration classes and their beans in their declaration order
- it then builds all the beans **in their instantiation order**

As you register the datasource `myds` at build time in its configuration class, it happens to be registered in time to be autowired in other beans when `repoConf` is built **before** any other beans using them. But this is never guaranteed by Spring Framework documentation and future versions could use a different approach without breaking their contract. Moreover, Spring does change initialization order to allow dependencies to be constructed before beans depending on them.

So the correct way here is to tell Spring that the `ADAO` bean *depends on* the configuration `RepoConf`. Just throw away all `Order` annotations which are no use here, and put a `@DependsOn` one. You code could be:

```
package com.so;
...

public class TestSpring {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Class<?>[] classes = new Class[]{AConf.class, ADAO.class, AService.class, RepoConf.class} ;
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(classes);
   }

   @Configuration
   public static class AConf {

      @Autowired
      AService aService;

   }

   @DependsOn("repoConf")
   @Repository
   public static class ADAO {

      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("myds")
      DataSource dataSource;
   }

   @Service
   public static class AService {

      @Autowired
      ADAO adao;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
         System.out.println("service init");
      }
   }

   @Configuration("repoConf")
   public static class RepoConf {

      @Autowired
      BeanFactory beanFactory;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
         ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
         configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("myds", new AbstractDataSource() {
            @Override
            public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
               return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
               return null;
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

`@DependsOn` ensures that `repoConf` will be created before `ADAO` making the datasource available for dependency injection.

Comment: For the first part of your answer, I upgraded springframework version to 4.2.1 which supports `@Order` on `@Configuration` classes (and also implemented `Ordered` interface), it did not work either. This is still an open issue for me. But yes, you are completely right about the way this specific case should be considered. I had successfully tried `@DependsOn`, just I was trying to avoid `@DependsOn`, It seems I cannot overrun :)

Comment: @px5x2 IMHO, manual registration of an injected bean should be avoided if possible because Spring will need special procession to find the bean. If you really need it I would not rely on configuration class ordering, because Spring can reorder bean construction when it detects dependancies (dependancies are constructed before dependant beans whenever possible). So you really should use explicit dependancy (`@DependsOn` annotation) in such a use case.