# Bean and Dependency Injection configuration from Database Instead XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Currently we have all service class configuration defined in Application-Context.xml file. Application context will be initialized during the application startup with all beans defined in the context file and spring handles dependency injection.

I am looking for a solution where it has to load particular service class during run time based on specific parameter from Database.

For example, there are two classes exist in code base such as FooService1.java and FooService2.java. Each class will have dependency with appropriate DAO class such as FooDAO1.java and FooDAO2.java.

Instead of defining these in applciation-context.xml file, a run time parameter will decide which service needs to be loaded and its corresponding DAO which needs to be injected. Basically what i am trying to achieve here is DB oriented Dependency Injection to keep all application context information in database instead of XML.

Tables would look like: SERVICE_BEANS, DAO_BEANS and some intermediate table to have dependency information.

I just saw JdbcBeanDefinitionReader class in spring. Can I use this to implement DB oriented DI? I don't see much example on this. Please let me know if anyone has any examples.

Comment: You can make custom implementation of `BeanFactory`, that will get bean definitions from database.

Comment: Thanks Ken! Do you know any sample application to refer? Are there any open source application/framework which has implemented custom bean factory?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have not seen ready to use implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate beans @ runtime and register them to spring-context.

Refer to [Registering beans(prototype) at runtime in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring)

Hope that helps !