# Can I Add a New Bean Element on my XML-Based Configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I have an XML-Based configuration just like this in Spring :

```
<bean id="bean101" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="singleton">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="xmlBeansMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xmlBeansMarshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://127.0.0.1/services/WebServices/xyz.asmx?wsdl" />
</bean>
<bean id="bean102" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" scope="singleton">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="xmlBeansMarshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xmlBeansMarshaller"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://127.0.0.1/XYZService/MyService/MyService.svc?wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

I would like to ask/verify if I can dynamically insert a new Bean element, for instance "Bean103" upon runtime? If yes, is it possible that the changes from this XML-based configuration would take effect without restarting the server? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could change your XML file before creating ApplicationContext from that file. You could also programmatically add/modify bean definitions which were loaded from XML file. Check answers to these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programmatically-to-spring-web-app-context and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606504/registering-beansprototype-at-runtime-in-spring

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know the result of this. :)